# Example of $(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)^c=\bigcap\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I learned the generalized De morgan's Theorem about family of sets, but I can't find any examples although I know how they are proved. Can you give me an example of sets that belong to $(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)^c=\bigcap\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r^c$?

"Theorem 8 The Generalized De Morgan's Theorem

Let {$A_r$|$r\in\Gamma$} be an arbitrary family of sets. Then

(a) $(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)^c=\bigcap\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r^c$  (b) $(\bigcap\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)^c=\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r^c$"

"
Theorem 6 De Morgan's Theorem

For any two sets A and B,

(a) $(AUB)^c$= $A^c \bigcap B^c$     (b) $(A∩B)^c$ = $A^c \bigcup B^c$
"
Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin.

[EDIT] I'm finding an example of Theorem 8, not of Theorem 6.

Comment: What do you mean you can't find any examples? By the theorem, _every_ indexed collection $\{ A_r \mid r \in \Gamma \}$ of sets (to be more precise, subsets of some "universal set") will work. As long as you understand the concepts in that last sentence, you really can't go wrong.

Comment: @epimorphic I was finding more concrete example of sets, rather than abstract definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Now, consider the subsets of $X$: $A = \{1,4,5\}$ and $B = \{2,3,5\}$.

Clearly, $A \cup B = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.  That means $(A \cup B)^{c} = \{6\}$.

But $A^{c} = \{2,3,6\}$ and $B^{c} = \{1,4,6\}$.  So $A^{c} \cap B^{c} = \{6 \}$.

That shows you at example, at least for the case of two sets, where $(A \cup B)^{c} = A^{c} \cap B^{c}$.